# How to write unit tests in Angular when using dateAdapter?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a component that takes a DateAdapter in the constructor - this is not a custom Date Adapter. I am using it to set the locale for my material date picker.

I just want a basic it("should create") test. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is a sample:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DateAdapter, NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { DateComponent } from './chart-title.component';

describe('DateComponent', () => {
  let component: DateComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DateComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DateComponent ],
      providers: [DateAdapter]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DateComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I had to add DateAdapter to the providers in my app.module.ts

Comment: Cool, I was thinking it was that too but wanted to get context.